# FFMPEG installed but not found

Tags: ffmpeg, configure, phash

I'm trying to install [pHash](http://www.phash.org/) , but when I execute `./configure` this message is returned:

```
...

*** Configuring video Hash ***

checking whether FFmpeg is present... checking for avcodec_alloc_frame in -lavcodec... no
configure: error: 

*** libavcodec not found.
You need FFmpeg. Get it at <http://ffmpeg.org/>
```

But FFMPEG is correctly installed, in fact executing `ffmpeg` it returns:

```
ffmpeg version 3.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)
  configuration: 
  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
```

Why this happens?

Comment: Check if you have `libavcodec-dev` installed

Comment: You mean you just installed it, or it was already installed? Did it solve your problem?

Comment: It was already installed. I solved with the most brute force solution: format the pc (was nearly empty) and install Ubuntu 16 (which supports again FFMPEG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I didn't solve the problem on Ubuntu 15. I installed Ubuntu 16 (which include FFMPEG again) and everything went fine.

Comment: maybe next time you can try this auto installer for ubuntu : https://github.com/razzbee/ffmpeg_installer